# MySQL Select Statement - GROUP BY/Unique

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm currently using PHP/MySQL to select some data from my database.  My current SELECT statement is:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpm WHERE receiver_id ='$usrID' GROUP BY 
thread_id ORDER BY unique_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

There are some columns that have the same "thread-id", thus, I am using the GROUP BY, so that only one "thread-id" column is selected.  Everything works fine with the grouping, however, it is selecting the first 'thread-id' column, and not the most recent (which is what I want).

For example, there are 4 columns all with the same thread_id:

```
thread_id    unique_id
  222            1
  222            2
  222            3
  222            4
```

When I do the GROUP BY, I would like it to retrieve the one with unique id 4 (the most recently created column), not unique id 1 (the oldest column created).

Any ideas on how to achieve this with my SELECT statement?  Thanks.

Comment: Your query may have a sql injection vulnerability because you are not parameterizing your query or using mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: Thanks for the replies:

Here is what I am currently using:

$data = mysql_query("SELECT 
tblpm.thread_id, tblpm.receiver_id, tblpm.title, MAX(tblpm.content), tblpm.date_sent, tblpm.sender_id, tblpm.read_pref, MAX(tblpm.id) as unique_id, 
tblusers.usrFirst AS first_name, 
tblusers.usrLast AS last_name 
FROM tblpm 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblusers 
ON tblpm.sender_id=tblusers.usrID 
WHERE receiver_id ='$usrID' 
GROUP BY thread_id 
ORDER BY unique_id DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());

Comment: However, when I try to display the most recent "content" column, it still shows the first "content" field, not the most recent.  As you can see, I'm trying to invoke MAX(tblpm.content), but that does not seem to get the job done.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT thread_id, MAX(unique_id)
FROM tblpm
GROUP by thread_id
```

so:

```
mysql_query(<<<END
SELECT thread_id, MAX(unique_id)
FROM tblpm
WHERE receiver_id ='$usrID'
GROUP by thread_id
END
) or die(mysql_error());
```

and of course make sure you escape $usrID if it comes from the browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT thread_id, unique_id 
FROM tblpm
WHERE receiver_id = '$usrID'
GROUP BY thread_id
ORDER BY unique_id DESC;
```